# AngularJS Validation: how do I trigger validation on button click?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a form that has a series of inputs along with the option of adding more inputs by clicking a button. Each input is required and has $.touched validators already on them, so if a user touches them, they validate properly.

However, if the user hasn't filled out all of the existing inputs, clicking the add button (which is *not* a form submission) should prevent more inputs from being added (done), and it should trigger the validators on the inputs so that the user has to fill them out.

I have been unable to make that happen. I'm perplexed as to why I can't just arbitrarily fire validation for other elements on an ng-click event.

How do I trigger validation on inputs on a button click, even if the user has not interacted with those fields?

Plunker to show a rough idea of what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/LjMz5Ad19izthgKTK6Pi

```
<input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="editContactsForm.Name" ng-maxlength="100" required />
<small class="error" ng-show="(editContactsForm.Name.$error.required && editContactsForm.Name.$dirty) || (editContactsForm.Name.$error.required  && editContactsForm.Name.$touched)">This is a required field.</small>

<br/>
<input type="text" name="Name2" ng-model="editContactsForm.Name2" ng-maxlength="100" required />
<small class="error" ng-show="(editContactsForm.Name2.$error.required && editContactsForm.ContactTitle.$dirty) || (editContactsForm.Name2.$error.required  && editContactsForm.Name2.$touched)">This is a required field.</small>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see any `form` on your `plunker`, you will need it for manual validation.

You can use `$setSubmitted` which allows you to do that, in your click handler you can check for form validation and do nothing then:

```
addContent = function(form) {
   form.$setSubmitted();
   if(form.$invalid){
      return;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Weird, form tag was there, I must have accidentally removed it. Either way I do have a fully fleshed out form on the real thing, validators function, etc.